# delete if two conditions meet in sas

Tags: arrays, sas, conditional-statements

I have a rather complex scenario.

```
ID  cola   colb
1    10     0
1    11     1
2    12     0
2    13     1
2    15     2
3    11     0
4    12     0
5    12     0
5    15     1
6    10     0
```

Now I want to delete all IDs if cola eq 12 and colb = 0

So I need to delete all cases of id = 2, one case of id =4, all cases of  id =5

So essentially as soon as criteria of cola eq 12 and colb eq 0 is satisfied for any id, all instances of that id need to be deleted.

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DL00e.jpg I am not sure how can I edit table in the interface.

Comment: Please post what you've tried first. Basically, you need to first determine the IDs that need to be removed and then remove the IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to try also this way, it uses proc sql that could be faster for long datasets.

STEP to create data following your example

```
data work.input;
    length id 3. cola 3. colb 3.;
    input id cola colb;
    infile datalines dsd;
        datalines;
            1,    10,     0
            1,    11,    1
            2,    12,     0
            2,    13,     1
            2,   15,     2
            3,    11,     0
            4,    12,     0
            5,    12,     0
            5,    15,     1
            6,   10,     0
        ;
run;
```

STEP that actually does what you ask for:

```
proc sql noprint;

    select id into :id_list_to_remove separated by ','
    from work.input
    where cola=12 and colb=0
    ;

    create table output as
    select * 
    from work.input
    where id not in (&id_list_to_remove.)
    ;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it with one datastep if you don't have too many observations. Keep a running flag of the ID numbers that satisfy the condition, put them into a macro variable and call the macro variable in an if statement:

```
data want (drop = flag);
  length flag $200;
  set have end = eof;

  retain flag;

  if cola = 12 and colb = 0 then flag = cat(strip(put(ID,8.))," ",flag);

  if eof then call symputx("keepMe", flag);

  if ID not in (&keepMe);
run;
```

Can also be done for any size number data with more datasteps:

```
data want;
  set have;

  if cola = 12 and colb = 0 then flag = 1;
  else flag = 0;

run;

proc sort data = want;
  by ID descending flag;
run;

data want_final (drop = sum flag);
  set want;
  by ID;
  sum + flag;
  if first.id then sum = flag;

  if sum = 0;

run;
```